# Wiremock is throwing 422 error in place 400 in custom response using response defination

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, wiremock

**Below is the code for request filter class, which is expected to return the 400 error but getting 422 (UnProcessable Entity) in this case** Even though the badRequest() method is used with responseDefination, 422 is getting thrown.

Is this the expected error for bad request in wiremock, or there is some thing which is getting missed in the implementation part.

Below is the attached image of an error in postman.
[image: postman error image]

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.wiremock.errorhandler.BadRequestError;
import com.example.wiremock.errorhandler.MockError;
import com.example.wiremock.errorhandler.MockErrorResponse;
import com.example.wiremock.luukuresponse.LuukkuBasicInfoResponse;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
  import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors;
  import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors.Error;
   import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors.Error.Source;
  import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Json;
  import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.requestfilter.RequestFilterAction;
  import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.requestfilter.StubRequestFilter;
  import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.HttpHeader;
  import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.Request;
  import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.ResponseDefinition;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;


  @Component
public class BasicAuthRequestFilter extends StubRequestFilter { 



public String decodeJwt(String token) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String payload = token.split("\\.")[1];
    return new String(Base64.decodeBase64(payload), "UTF-8");
}


@Override
public RequestFilterAction filter(Request request){
        
    if (request.header("Authorization").firstValue().matches("Bearer [a-zA-Z0-9&._-]{1,}")) {
        
        String authtoken = request.header("Authorization").firstValue();
        
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        
         Errors errors;

        String str;
        try {
            
            String pattern = "^\\S{4}75-\\S{4}$";
            
            str = decodeJwt(authtoken);
            
            Token token = objectMapper.readValue(str, Token.class);
            
            String test = token.getRepresentation().getId();
            
            if(test.matches(pattern)) {
                
                Error error = new Error(400, null, "response", null);
                List<Error> listOfErros = new ArrayList<>();
                listOfErros.add(error);
                            
                Errors errorList = new Errors(listOfErros);

                return RequestFilterAction.stopWith(ResponseDefinition.badRequest(errorList));
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException  | JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return RequestFilterAction.continueWith(request);
    }
    return null;

    
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "Authorization";
}
```

Comment: Could it be your context parameter in the URL that has a space (not encoded)?

Comment: I tried without space but still the same result.